# PostThreadMessage sets GetLastError to 1444

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

In `PostThreadMessage` my thread ID is correct, but I am getting the error 1444 ("Invalid thread identifier. ").

Anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: How do you know your thread id is correct? Because apparently it's not.

Comment: 0% acceptance on answers drives up my motivation to help.  NOT.  Please accept some answers on previous questions and maybe someone will lend a hand!

Comment: @GManNickG Um, because it was given by windows EnumProcess and matches the id given by task managers... That's how, so apparently, at least in my case, it does match and I still get that error. So, Apparently your wrong in implying that the only way to get the error is if the id is invalid.

Comment: @AbstractDissonance: That wasn't my implication. One of the basic tactics in debugging is to check your assumptions, I was merely asking where the thread ID came from and what evidence there was to suggest it was correct. Imagine trying to debug this with the assumption that ID is correct when, in fact, it's not; this would be a huge waste of time. Chill out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OS is the authority on whether thread IDs are valid, so if it's telling you your ID is invalid, then your ID is probably invalid. You have to trust the error codes until you can prove they're wrong, or else there's no use checking them at all. Before blaming the OS, make sure you've ruled out all other possibilities. Here are some examples:

- Maybe you used the thread *handle* instead.
- Maybe the thread has finished running already.
- Maybe the thread wasn't created successfully in the first place. Make sure you check the return value from CreateThread.
- Maybe the thread belongs to a process running on a different desktop.
- Maybe the thread doesn't have a message queue. A thread can create a message queue for itself by calling GetMessage or PeekMessage, for example.

Comment: By the way, I got those last two failure reasons by reading the [documentation for `PostThreadMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644946.aspx); it mentions `ERROR_INVALID_THREAD_ID` all over the place.